# On which partition is Ubuntu located?

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, delete

I'm trying to delete the Ubuntu partition and then later I'm planning on running Ubuntu through VitualBox on Windows 7. The problem is I don't know which partition is Ubuntu so I can use that space for Windows. 
[image: Screenshot of Disk Management utility]

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your partitions

[image]

If you used WUBI to install Ubuntu its contained in your C:/programs. Just delete it using 'programs add/delete' under Windows.

It would have not installed Ubuntu into a separate partition.

According to your partition table the only OS on that computer is the primary Windows OS.

Comment: The two partitions look like your C:\ (windows) and the recovery partition (put there by manufacturers so they can be cheap and not give your CDs).